# How to return list of value based on another list of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if there is a way to return a list of data similar to vlookup. except it returns a list of values instead of a single value.

for example.
I have a table with headers

| A | B | C | E | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

and another table with value I am trying to look up

| Type | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A | 34 |
| B | 10 |
| C | 2 |
| E | 5 |
| C | 9 |

What I wanted to do is to get the cost of each type in my table 1 and do sumproduct of the value

so the end result would be
A - 34*1 + E - 5*1, which is 39

wonder if there is a way for me to pull the reference value based on the entire list of my header and results output like 34, 10,2,5,9

I can get my result by addition and multiplication. but that will be a lot of work, or vlookup for very single type to get each cost and both will result in

34*1+10*0+2*0+5*1+9*0

but don't think this is sufficient enough for me.

if you guys have any idea, thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there a typo in your lookup table - there are two values for C? Which version of Excel do you have

Comment: hi. thank you for catching this!. the 2nd C should be D instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `SUM` Up an `XLOOKUP`

**`SUM`/`XLOOKUP`**

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A6,Sheet1!A1:E1,Sheet1!A2:E2,0)*Sheet2!B2:B6)
=SUM(XLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1:E1,Sheet2!A2:A6,Sheet2!B2:B6,0)*Sheet1!A2:E2)
```

**LET**

```
=LET(DataCols,Sheet2!A2:B6,MultiRows,Sheet1!A1:E2,
    lData,TAKE(DataCols,,1),vData,TAKE(DataCols,,-1),
    lMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,1),vMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,-1),
SUM(XLOOKUP(lData,lMulti,vMulti,0)*vData))
```

or the other way around (see the last line).

```
=LET(DataCols,Sheet2!A2:B6,MultiRows,Sheet1!A1:E2,
    lData,TAKE(DataCols,,1),vData,TAKE(DataCols,,-1),
    lMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,1),vMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,-1),
SUM(XLOOKUP(lMulti,lData,vData,0)*vMulti))
```

[image]

**How does `XLOOKUP(lData,lMulti,vMulti,0)` work...**

... since `lData` is a column, while `lMulti` and `vMulti` are rows?

- In simple words, here is how I'm seeing what is happening:

  - Create an array of size `lData`.
  - Loop through each cell (element) of `lData` and attempt to find a match in `lMulti`.
  - If found return the associated value, the value at the same index (column in this case), from `vMulti` and put it in the array.
  - If not found, put a zero instead (4th parameter; error if omitted).
  - When done, return the array.
- To conclude, only the 2nd and 3rd parameters (ranges, arrays) of `XLOOKUP` need to be of the same size while the result will always be an array of the same size as the 1st parameter (range, array).

**Why use `LET`...**

... since the formula becomes much longer?

- The formula actually becomes more readable (once you get used to it) and often more efficient.
- Also, it could be considered the first step in getting used to using the `LAMBDA` function to create your own functions.
- Consider this:

  ```
  =LAMBDA(DataCols,MultiRows,LET(
      lData,TAKE(DataCols,,1),vData,TAKE(DataCols,,-1),
      lMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,1),vMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,-1), 
  SUM(XLOOKUP(lData,lMulti,vMulti,0)*vData)))(Sheet2!A2:B6,Sheet1!A1:E2)
  ```
- You can use the part before the last parentheses...

  ```
  =LAMBDA(DataCols,MultiRows,LET(
      lData,TAKE(DataCols,,1),vData,TAKE(DataCols,,-1),
      lMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,1),vMulti,TAKE(MultiRows,-1), 
  SUM(XLOOKUP(lData,lMulti,vMulti,0)*vData)))
  ```

  ... to create a name, e.g. `MultiLookup`.
- Now, in this workbook, you can use the new function with the simple...

  ```
  =MultiLookup(Sheet2!A2:B6,Sheet1!A1:E2)
  ```

  ... where you can easily use it for different ranges.

Comment: Thank you so much! never used lambda before and this is so new to me! question to people we are excel advanced users, how can I become an excel expert like you are? It is so fun but I know I am not knowing a lot of stuffs about excel

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(Types,A1:E1,
Counts,A2:E2,
Lookup,I2:J6,
Costs,MAP(Types,LAMBDA(v,INDEX(Lookup,MATCH(v,CHOOSECOLS(Lookup,1),0),2))),
SUM(Costs*Counts))
```

[image]

Comment: woo, map and lambda is so new to me. I am looking at the explanation for lambda. mind explain a bit on what the v is ?